# Is there a compilation of old Lehman research out there?

Tags: reference-request, research, papers

Like the title says.

Does anyone know of any compilations or have any old papers they'd like to share? So far, I've only found a few sporadic pieces that are easily Googled for.

Comment: what kind of products (equities, fixed income, derivatives, etc.) are you looking at?

Comment: I'm mostly interested in the Fixed Income Quant Research (Tuckman et al) but I figured that the community as a whole would be interested in the whole scope of quant research

Comment: I'm actually looking for the same thing.

Comment: I liked their notes on interest rate curces (par, zero, forward) very much and I always recommend them to colleagues new to the field.

Answer (score 1):

This is **NOT** a reply. I am just trying to figure out the papers that OP is looking for.

Kch, as per Tuckman's [CV](http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~sternfin/btuckman/pdfs/tuckmancv.pdf), at Lehman he produced the following papers:

- “Flash: Tri-Party Repo Infrastructure Reform,” CFS, February 2011.
- “Update: the Clearing Mandate in Dodd-Frank, Systemic Risk, and
  Competition,” CFS, June 2011.
- “Amending Safe Harbors to Reduce Systemic Risk in OTC Derivatives
  Markets,” CFS, April 2010.
- “Systemic Risk and the Tri-Party Repo Clearing Banks,” CFS, February
- “Consistent Pricing of FX Forwards, Cross-Currency Basis Swaps, and
  Interest Rate Swaps in Several Currencies,” w/ J.B. Homé, December, 2003. Internal Circulation Only.
- “Macro-Awareness in Relative Value Trading,” October, 2003.
- “The FEDISCOPE,” w/ D. Calistru, September, 2003.
- “Interest Rate Parity, Basis Swaps, and Cross-Currency Basis Swaps,”
  w/ P. Porfirio, June, 2003.
- “Revisiting the Rate-Dependence of Volatility,” w/ G. Marone,
  February, 2003.
- “Measures of Asset Swap Spreads and their Corresponding Trades,”
  January, 2003.

Could you upload the ones that you have and maybe other members will upload what they have?